# Brightness Notification on Xubuntu Shrunk after Update

Tags: xubuntu, notification

My brightness notification has shrunk. It was fine before I installed the updates after installing Xubuntu 14.04. I first noticed after booting for the first time after the upgrade.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The brightness notification is that small box under the volume notification. As you can see it's only the brighness notification that's affected.

How can I revert this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing some testing (and a few reinstalls) I found that this error was not caused by an update, but was first noticed after I rebooted after doing a software update. The cause was an improper use of [this](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) fix I used to get the brightness control to adjust. I properly used the fix and now everything is as it should be.